# iPython Notebook not embedding animations

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I've been trying to embed an animation into an iPython notebook but without success. I'm using the latest version of Enthought Canopy (python 2.7.3) on a Mac running 10.8.5 using Safari as my default browser.

After much failed experimentation, I tried using this code

```
%pylab inline

from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

VIDEO_TAG = """<video controls>
 <source src="data:video/x-m4v;base64,{0}" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>"""

def anim_to_html(anim):
    if not hasattr(anim, '_encoded_video'):
            with NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.mp4') as f:
            anim.save(f.name, fps=20, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
            video = open(f.name, "rb").read()
        anim._encoded_video = video.encode("base64")

    return VIDEO_TAG.format(anim._encoded_video)

from IPython.display import HTML

def display_animation(anim):
    plt.close(anim._fig)
    return HTML(anim_to_html(anim))  


from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True)

# call our new function to display the animation
display_animation(anim)
```

from jake Vanderplas on the web. I installed ffmpeg.

On running the code I get the video progress bar, but no graph, just an empty space above the video progress bar.

After a couple of days of working on this I've not found a solution (the above is the closest I've come to). Can anyone see what's going wrong or suggestions to try?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved in Jessica Hamrick's comment on Jake Vanderplas's blog at https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/05/12/embedding-matplotlib-animations/

She added added two additional items to the extra_args argument:

extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p']